# Подскажите как отобразить аватарку email-отправителя

Tags: php, wordpress, email

В общем есть почта на хостинге. при отправление на email пользователю ему приходит в таком виде: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотел бы узнать как сделать вот так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какие то способы может php или еще какие то как это реализовать. Знаю что есть вариант это создать на какой то из популярных почт и там загрузить аватар. Но хотел бы узнать и другие варианты если они такие имеются. Или может кто уже сталкивался и делал.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravatar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем понял регистрирую на свою почту в Граватар и там загружаю свою аватарку. Спасибо вопрос закрыт.

Comment: У каждого почтового сервиса свои методы рисования аватарок. Граватар используют далеко не все