# Как добавить портрет в скрипте обратной связи

Tags: php, форма, связи

Имеется форма обратной связи. Там же скрипт отправки письма на почту пользователю (успешная регистрация, номер заявки и т.д.).
Почта отправляется с noreply адреса. То есть - такого ящика в принципе не существует.
Хочу, чтоб пользователь, воспользовавшийся формой, получая почту на Яндекс (не могу сказать точно - на всех почтовых сервисах или нет) видел значок, как в примере на скрине.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=gravatar&searchOn=3)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin это не имеет никакого отношения к gravatar

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ...причём я об этом [сообщал ещё в ноябре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1471892#comment2634532_1471898)

Comment: @andreymal ну не догадался что в возможных дубликатах будет упомянуто слово "граватар", а не "gravatar". значит, дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=gravatar&searchOn=3) или [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin это не имеет никакого отношения и к слову "граватар" тоже

Comment: @andreymal я написал всего лишь: «дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=gravatar&searchOn=3) или [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80)». совершенно не понимаю, что именно вас не устроило. по второй ссылке ведь даже доступен ваш ноябрьский комментарий (написали бы ответ, так и ответ фигурировал бы).